# i am running prisma deploy , it show me error Could not connect to server at http://localhost:3000. Please check if your server is running

Tags: docker, prisma

> Could not connect to server at http://localhost:3000. Please check if your server is running.
>
> Get in touch if you need help: https://spectrum.chat/prisma
>   To get more detailed output, run `$ export DEBUG="*"`

I am running on windows 10 home , I have used docker toolbox

**docker-compose** file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.32
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 3000
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mysql
            host: mysql
            port: 3306
            user: root
            password: prisma
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: prisma
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  mysql: ~
```

**prisma.yml** file:

```
endpoint: http://localhost:3000
datamodel: datamodel.prisma
```